# Parse: Where do I place my pointer column to link 2 classes and how does this affect ACL?

Tags: pointers, database-design, parse-platform, acl

So I have 2 classes, 1st is the main Group class and the other is the Group_Detail class.

Group class would only be editable by the owner (group creator) while Group_Detail would only be editable by group admins.

My question is where would it be better to place the objectId pointer column to link these 2 classes? In Group_Detail placing the Group_objectId or in Group with the Group_Detail_objectId? Does it matter? How does this affect ACL considering I need admins to only be able to edit the Group_Detail class.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few more searches, I found [this answer](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-query-using-pfrelation-when-i-just-have-pfuser). Basically it doesn't matter which side of the relationship contains the column. You will just need to use a whereKey equalTo search to find all related data.

Hope this helps anyone wondering the same.